# Eevee shadow problem

Tags: rendering, shadows, eevee-render-engine

[image]

Recently I downloaded blender 2.8 for the new real-time render engine, but then I found out that the shadow in the eevee is really unexpected. Just like shown above, the quality of the shadow is bad and the movement of the shadow is also strange when I move the object.
The lamp is a sunlight, and the sphere and the plane are just preset meshes.
Could you tell me what adjustment do I need to create a normal shadow?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished experimental development software

Comment: is it from view port only or when you render also. if it's from viewport only, then you can't complain; 
A) it's still in alpha version
B) we never had shadows on viewport shading, so give them time, or there's a setting some where, to increase the sampling or anti-aliasing of the shadows.

Comment: Read the excelent anwser to this post: [**How does evee work**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work/120378#120378) to understand the main differences. Other useful information here: [**Eevee and cycles render liighting differences**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences)

Answer (score 3):

Look at that ! i had the exact same issue, and i found you can play with the softness of your light here... 
[image]

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! (I do wonder how much it taxes performance though, but obviously thats impossible to avoid).