# Eevee - Mesh light illuminating scene from within glass (i.e., light bulb)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass, emission

I'm trying to light a scene in Eevee using light bulbs. I have a filament (emission object) within a glass object. Basically, I'm able to see the emission object through the glass, but the light is not escaping the glass to illuminate the scene. Here are two renders. In both cases, world lighting set to 0, no other light except the emission ball in the middle. Glass ball has a small solidify modifier to make it empty inside.

Emission ball outside of glass ball. Note you can see through glass ball, and emission ball illuminates scene.

[image]

Emission ball within glass ball. No exterior illumination.

[image]

Note light probes are used for illumination from the emission mesh, and the reason the cube within the ball in the second one is not illuminated (even within the glass ball) is because there is no probe within the glass ball.

Tons of references on glass shaders, but nothing specifically on this question as far as I can find. Only one reference I've found to this is "turn off any glass during baking". Is that the only option? Is Eevee not capable of what I'm trying to do?

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1276SA_p_O1R8LkjM41ZtZCjCPKUJCvr0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

[image: Final]

Couple of things to note here.

1. **Mesh lights** do not work in EEVEE the same as **Lights** (mainly they do not cast shadows). I've pointed to it here: [In Blender 2.8, how do I light an EEVEE scene with an HDR?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124047/in-blender-2-8-how-do-i-light-an-eevee-scene-with-an-hdr)
2. You can use **Point Light** to have effect you want without baking anything. Use **Radius** and **Strength** to manipulate it.
3. You need to turn on **Screen Space Reflections** with **Refraction** for your scene:

   [image: scene]
4. For the **Glass** material you need to properly set below options to be able to see light source and allow it to light the scene:

   [image: glass]
5. Keep **Solidify modifier** on the Bulb object. What is strange is that even with value 0 it is working fine :)