# How can I get HDRI shadows in an Eevee scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, hdri

I'm currently testing Eevee.  Seems so promising !

Here, i'm trying to make my Eevee render the closest I can to my previous render Cycles of the same scene.
This scene do not have any lights but an HDRI background.

Thing is, the renders looks very, very different.  How can I improve this ?

Cycles:
[image: Cycles]

Eevee:
[image: Eevee]

And [here's the blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5euqtsvu824mpgv/eeveeTest.blend?dl=1).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, the reason for the lighting difference is that in the scene you provided, everything is lit by a World HDRI only. Eevee by default can only produce shadows from Light objects, so even if you turn the respectable options on, there won't be any indirect shadows visible. This is a technical limitation. Duarte in the [linked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences) answer elaborates on this, so there's no need to re-iterate everything here.

However, there is a quick solution to at least get a lot closer to the Cycles render: Adding an **Irradiance Volume Light Probe** allows you to bake the lighting solution into the scene dynamically.

To do that, in the 3D Viewport use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> `Light Probe` -> `Irradiance Volume`.

[image]

Scale it up to encompass the areas of your scene which are visible through the camera. After that, in the Render Settings, use `Indirect Lighting` -> `Bake Indirect Lighting`. The scene will jitter a bit while the solution is baked. Afterwards, it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this description! This seems to work well for a static scene.

However, baking the lighting does not work if (for example) I have a node based world sky with changing colors. Do you know of any solutions outside of rendering in cycles that would allow reasonable shadow casting?

Comment: @tyler Just bake it on each frame?

Comment: @tyler just came across an add-on that could do the job for animations, though I have not tested it myself yet https://gumroad.com/l/PgyXc