# When I add environment texture to world node object shadow disappears

Tags: light, shadows

When I add environment texture to world node my object shadow disappear.

Do I need to turn off background strength?
I want to make my object to look like background so I lost shadow that I wanted

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is not that the shadow dispappears, but it is not as dark... Why? Because the environment will illuminate that area. Think of the environment as a giant sphere that surrounds the scene, emitting light from every pixel of the image texture used. So the question is: if you like the shadows without the world texture, do you really need it? Else just bring down the strenght.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to light up your scene with an Environment Texture it depends on which render engine you are using.

If you use **Cycles** an `HDRI` in the `Environment Texture` node should do the job. It looks like you are using a PNG file. You can use HDRIs that are shipped with Blender or download them from https://hdrihaven.com for example. See [How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128499/107598) for details. Switch to `Rendered` view to see the shadows (<kbd>Z</kbd>). It doesn't show up in `Material Preview` view.

If you use **Eevee** you need extra lights in your scene to have objects cast shadows because the Eevee renderer cannot use the light info of the HDR image. See
[How can I get HDRI shadows in an Eevee scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128120/107598) for details.