# Shadows from the background (EEVEE)

Tags: shadows

Can the background (environment map) generate soft shadows in the EEVEE renderer?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128120/how-can-i-get-hdri-shadows-in-an-eevee-scene/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99631/how-to-make-mesh-lights-work-in-blender-eevee https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101244/does-the-blender-eevee-rendering-engine-really-have-indirect-lighting

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a *Light Probe > Irradiance Volume* around your scene and click on *Bake Indirect Lighting* in the *Render panel > Indirect Lighting*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is this the only way? Is it possible to create a Shadw Map shadow type (like from other light types) from the background?

Comment: Sure, you can bake the shadows in Cycles if this is what you mean