# CYCLES vs EEVEE

Tags: modeling

I just switched to 2.8 last week and only got a chance to play around with it. I was excited about the EEVEE renderer as advertised so I tried do a comparison between the two (CYCLES vs EEVEE) but I think I'm doing something wrong in here.

If you notice the EEVEE sample image, it doesn't look anything better or at least the same as the CYCLES image.

Can someone please tell me where i did wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not look right, but in general I don't think Eevee is supposed to look better than Cycles. It is just a lot faster, optimally real time.

Comment: Try to attach the blend file in your question.

Comment: Read the excelent anwser to this post: [**How does evee work**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work/120378#120378) to understand the main differences. Other useful information here: [**Eevee and cycles render liighting differences**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences)

Comment: Recommended reading: [**Cycles vs Eevee, 15 limitations on real time rendering**](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Answer (score 8):

So, there's a lot of things that are going on.

Eevee is a fundamentally different render engine than cycles. And while node-compatibility is kept between the two, lighting in general doesn't transfer as well.

Firstly, Eevee doesn't support emissive materials. Instead it relies on lamps. These lamps don't port over from cycles easily either, you need to adjust their power.

Furthermore Eevee doesn't do transparency out of the box. You'll need to enable that checkbox under "Screenspace Refraction, and then again under the material settings.

[image: The Checkbox in question, in the Materials Tab.]

I'm adding this because, judging by the amount of noise in your scene, it's likely that you have a glass pane in that window.

Please provide further details on your lamps and setup if any of this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Cycles and eevee both have different light values, you'll have to use different values in eevee to match the lighting in cycles, by default the lights are set to 1 if you change from cycles to eevee. For realistic lighting and reflections you will have to enable Screen space reflections, use light probes and bake indirect lighting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see in your outliner, so I'm not sure, but if you used a plane with emission material insted of lighting that could be the problem.[explanation](https://youtu.be/twr9u8GUscc?list=PLjEaoINr3zgH1JI7FtPX_Q9OGFhP-HCUV&t=264)

Comment: I'm actually using LAMPS?? I added a new IMAGE....does this help?