# White squares in eevee render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

While I render using the new eevee engine, the render has squares in it. [image]

I have Intel HD 620 integrated GPU and all GPU drivers are up-to-date. I can render it good in Cycles but not in Eevee? Why?

Comment: "*I can render it good in Cycles but not in Eevee? Why?*" https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work

Comment: I found the problem. Can anyone close this question or should I delete it

Comment: You should post an answer below with the solution and a small description of the steps taken, so it can help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

When I used add material option it added a principled bsdf node, I replaced it with Diffuse BSDF and it worked correctly. I don't know how. It's a possible workaround.