# Colors in object mode are different to render mode

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, color

Alright so I have been trying to figure this out when I am in object mode making materials for my low poly island when I texture a face the color is dark that when I would be in render mode.[image: colors are dark]
When I pick the color it shows differently to what is shown, I have factory reset and still not fixed.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any lights? They don't get calculated in solid view mode. Solid view is just a vague approximation. You have to render your scene to judge the correct lighting and shading. If you like the OpenGL solid mode preview, you can render the opengl solid preview.

Comment: Yes but is there a way of viewing correct colors cause I need to save as much time as possible to get my project complete

Comment: Shift Z calls the render preview in the 3D viewport.

Comment: Or you can save the OpenGl preview.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences/123734#123734

Comment: Thank you Leander could you put it as a answer so I can say it's the solution, and Duarte I'm on Blender 2.79 not 2.8

Answer (score -1):

The problem am seeing there is SPECULAR problem.

The solution will be to change the SPECULAR COLOR to something dark,

or

Change the SPECULAR INTENSITY from 0.5 to 0 in the material panel