# Imitating Cycles renders with Eevee?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

Seeing as how cycles renders are really taxing and causes really high CPU temps. Is there away to fake or imitate cycles renders with eevee? what i mean is. Are there ways to get eevee to look just as good as cycles?. Or are there ways to cloud render scenes and not utilize your own hardware for high quality renders?.

Comment: Eevee can't match Cycles when it comes to global illumination especially when you have something like hair in your scene. It can come pretty close though, see https://twitter.com/artificial3d/status/1151868975464140800 You'll notice what I said about the hair, but it still looks very good. Cloud rendering is always possible, but depends on your budget.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences/123734#123734

Comment: Thank you for your input. And i see what you mean and your right it still does look pretty good though.