# Render looks darker than Look Dev mode

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have been texture painting in look dev mode. But when i try to render it, everything looks very dark. I have 3 sun lights in my scene, ambient turned on in Eevee settings. What am i missing? I really like the look of my scene in Look Dev mode, how can i achieve the same look when my scene is rendered too?

[image]

Comment: Thanks! i can now render the viewport of look dev which is ok. But  rendered mode is still the same. If i were to export my objects to a game engine, would they look the same in the game engine, as they would in look dev mode?

Comment: That depends on the lighting in the game engine.  In the render your lighting is determined by your world background settings and any additional lighting you have in your scene

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences/123734#123734

Answer (score 2):

this is happening because you have different lighting setup in rendered view to the lookdev mode in lookdev mode lighting is done through hdri
[image: scrrenshot]

if you just download the same hdri or just go to the blender's directory for that hdri then you can have same look

Comment: So I just have to apply that hdri as the world material?