# Rendered image different than render preview

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am having this issue when everything looks good and ready to render the image, but once it is rendered the material is discolored. I changed the settings in the viewport shading. I unclicked the Scene Lights, Scene world, enabling the metallic color and world reflection to be visible on the rendered outcome. The light seems to be the same in both views. What could cause that?

[image: What the object should look like]

[image: My render preview]

[image: What the bad lighting render looks like]

Comment: Your environment is obviously *black* hence no reflections: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155793/render-looks-darker-than-look-dev-mode/155804#155804

Answer (score 1):

Viewport shading is only preview, that means the HDRI when you uncheck the world lighting will not be used in real render. So if you want to use HDRI, the correct way is to use real HDRI from World properties, change the color to Environment, select HDRI that you have (you can download from [HDRIhaven.com](https://hdrihaven.com/)  or use the one included in Blender (I think they are lower resolution) from Blender folder \2.82\2.82\Datafiles\Studiolights\World (change the path according to version).

*but actually you can just render from the viewport in View > Viewport Render Image/Animation, it's just you may want to disable Gizmos, change viewport samples per pixel, etc
but I recommend you go the usual path of rendering until you know what you're doing*