# Glossy shader not visible in renderer preview

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials

I have a problem with the glossy shader. I'd like for it to be visible in renderer preview the same way that it's visible in material preview. How do I do that?
Here is a picture of how it looks in material preview mode: 
[image]

And here is how it looks in renderer preview mode:

[image]

Comment: Hello, in Material Preview, there is an HDRI that is reflected by the objects, so it won't appear in the same way in Rendered, in Rendered it will all depends on your environment, lights and world

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you give me some tips on how to make it look similar to the way it looks in material preview mode? I need this look for my animation to be visible.

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155793/render-looks-darker-than-look-dev-mode or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172755/rendered-image-different-than-render-preview or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179960/render-looks-way-different-from-viewport-render-mode-how-can-i-fix-this

Comment: as Lemon says you can find the same HDRI image in a folder, then go in the Shader Editor, switch it to World, and plug a Texture > Environment Texture node into the Background node, upload the HDRI into the Environment Texture

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I'll try to do that right away.