# I am setting up three point light system and looks like noise is glitched

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

Currently when I change back to Cycles engine it looks fine but in EEVEE engine it shows up like this

[image: 1]]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack exchange! You do know that the materials assigned in cycles mode differ from that of eevee. Read this it might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences

Comment: If possible, can you attach the blend file?

Comment: Thank you guys i fixed my problem just restarting the blender i don't know what is the problem and I haven't applied any material on my object

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Properties > Render Properties > Shadows* and activate the *High Bit Depth* parameter.

[image: High Bit Depth parameter]

It worked for me.