# Can someone please explain why eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm still confused as to why there is yet another rendering engine packed into blender. I thought cycles was pretty good, what does eevee do better?

Comment: Answering this would actually be somewhat interesting, but since there are so many videos showing what Eevee can do out there, showing the real-time shading possibilities that allow you to see what a render with Cycles would maybe take hours to do (cleaner and more realistic yes, but slower), i leave this as a comment. Sorry, not saying it's not a good question, but very open, or not problem related, but rather opinion based. Short reason would be to allow faster look-dev, while also giving the option to **very** fast(er then cycles) render scenes and even short videos in good quality.

Comment: Okay, so the point is that when you're previewing stuff in the viewport, it's a lot faster than in cycles and blender render combined? Is this just for lighting or for everything? But then I can't really build materials. Cycles lost a lot of convenient material-building, now eevee will take even more from cycles.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences/123734#123734

Comment: So, neither are better at calculating physics, one is just for the accuracy of textures and materials and the other is for the speed of previewing them?