# Eevee vs Cycle Transparent Render Problem

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, light, eevee-render-engine

I been trying to figure out how to get the model I've been modeling to render in Cycle. I followed a tutorial and it was made for Eevee as you can see from the screenshot. It looks great but as soon as I render it in Eevee it looks bad.

When I switch to Cycle then the iris part is rendered with a lot of noise. I tried using Denoising but didn't fix it. I tried to increase the sample to 500 and it did sort of fixed the issue with the noise, but too way longer. Somehow with Cycle some of the detail were not shown and I thought Cycle would make it more realistic. Could someone please help me with it?

**Eevee Render**
[image]

**Cycle Render 300 Samples**
[image]

You can see on the Cycle Render that the top lighting reflection part is sharper and looks more fake.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences

Comment: Turn off the Bloom effect and you will see that Cycles is better. You can add Bloom effect to your Cycles render

Comment: I did have the Bloom effect on for Eevee but Cycle doesn't. I mean you said that Cycle without the bloom effect would look good, but it doesn't have the option on and it still looks bad.

Comment: I managed to get it fixed, but only the noisy part. So, adding the Denoising node from Compositing doesn't do anything. The noise stays the same as above with or without it. I instead use the original Denoising option and somehow that fixed the noise from the iris. However, I still am getting those sharp reflection as you can see from the second image.

Comment: I also got the Bloom effect fixed by using Glare in Compositing. Thank you guys!