# What is the difference between Evee and Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

As mentioned in the title i don't understand which differences are and when is better tu use one render than another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EEVEE and Cycles render lighting differences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123724/eevee-and-cycles-render-lighting-differences)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372