# Eevee: weird shadow artifacts

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I got those strange shadow artifacts when rendering with Eevee.
Does anyone knows what might cause it ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eevee shadow problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117986/eevee-shadow-problem). So now it gets asked twice every day...

Comment: yes, due to contact shadows softness. thanks!